# Error message that my post has too much code

Tags: support, code-formatting

I can't ask a question with code. I get a notice that my post is full of code, and I should add more deatil. What can I do? I already have my Java code, but I cannot post it in a question.

Comment: meta question. you should be guided :-)

Comment: Read the Help Center.

Comment: Try to explain what the problem is with plain words in order to not have only code in your question.

Comment: What do you mean "can not post it"? Can't figure out how, or aren't allowed to?

Comment: if you have questions about code, write explanation of problem, what you want for outcome, what happens now and give piece of code. NOT only code or ONLY explanation

Comment: Hey, the editor finally stopped a bad question from being posted. Unfortunately it appears it then generated one.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I will read the help menu. Don't blame me, am a novice around this forum

Answer (score 6):

On Stack Overflow we expect [questions (and answers) to be of certain quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards). To achieve that the site has a wide range of automatic quality filters, help pages and moderation tools.

I assume you posted a question with merely code. That is not something that is welcome on the site because we are not your debugging service.

The community has spend quite some time to create and improve the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that is now full of tips and advice on how to write a good post. Beyond that it provides links to external sites that have even more guidance. By reading it all and applying that to your question your post will pass the quality filter.

After the quality filter members of the community can upvote and downvote your question, leave comments or vote to close it if the question is still not up to the standards.

That is how the high-quality of the post on Stack Overflow is maintained.

So before you post your next question make sure your question is up to par.