# Is this comment fine or did I wrongly flag it as "unfriendly or unkind"?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags, unfriendly-or-unkind, specific-comment

I flagged [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72194490/javafx-making-a-post-request-using-org-apache-httpcomponents-fails#comment127559529_72194490) as "unfriendly or unkind":

> descibe your problem instead of typing nonsense text

No, it's about not the missing `r`, but the way of conveying that the "text" (code/error/question) is not useful.

"nonsense", IMO, depends on how it is taken/received by the reader.
It'd be fine if it is understood by its literal meaning, but it easily could be considered rude/in other ways.

Wouldn't it be better to avoid such misunderstandings?

Text mentioned in the comment is now deleted from the post by an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72194490/revisions)

[image]

Comment: Was the flag declined or do you just want to gauge what community at large thinks?

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine, no, it's still pending, and yes, the second one.

Comment: Do you feel "nonsense" is a bad way to describe the text "Stack overflow states I need more words Stack overflow states I need more words Stack overflow states I need more words Stack overflow states I need more words Stack overflow states I need more words Stack overflow states I need more words" in the question?

Comment: IMO, this one could be flagged NLN if this the first instance you stop, but that's my preference on not incurring the mod wrath (and R/A & U/U do tend to cause this) unless a comment is way over the line of respectful discourse. But, yeah, borderline wording if you ask me.

Comment: @francescalus, I saw the edit after posting this, but still, other words could've been used, right? After all, the question is not just that "nonsense text".

Comment: However, given the context provided above by @francescalus (I admit to not looking at the question before making the above comment), well, it does look like "nonsense" :)

Comment: The question isn't nonsense text , but the *"Stack overflow states I need more words"* is certainly nonsense. I wouldn't say the comment was unfriendly or unkind, however, it is NLN as an edit has been made to the question to remove the (nonsense) text. I would, personally, hope that a U/U flag would be declined on that comment.

Comment: I'm not judging whether "nonsense" is the best way of wording things here. Something like "your code is nonsense" is much more likely to be over the unkind line than "you've knowingly written nonsense to get past a filter which is complaining that you've not written enough text to accompany your code".

Comment: I agree that it is "nonsense", but then, StackOverflow's post editor's highly abnormal and unexpected behaviour and, with the fact that it still has not been improved, it too does look like "nonsense". It should be improved as it's so frustrating. I would support the OP just because of this.

Comment: I don't think the editor was at fault here, if I am honest, @TheAmateurCoder . The OP has just dumped their code and error; no details of what they've tried to fix the problem, no evidence of what they didn't understand when they researched the problem. These are things that are asked for in the guidelines; the editor correctly detected the lack of content and suggested they actually add content. Had the user actually put these things in, which they should be, they wouldn't have been informed that their question looked like it was just code.

Comment: It's not "*the post editor's highly abnormal and unexpected behavior*". It's the "[too much code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252422/2821954)" quality filter that affects low-rep users.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but it's not in other cases. The system should be improved IMO, as there would be many places where you have to add a lot of related code to make the post sensible.

Comment: Pretty much everyone is right and wrong in these cases. It is not rude, it is terse. But it is still written in a way that is unnecessarily confrontational and unhelpful. "Do better" is even more terse but pretty much says the same thing - as little as possible. Wrong to consider it rude, wrong to write comments like that.

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like we either used to have a close reason or some flagging guidance that used the word "nonsense"; at least a couple of Meta questions ask why something in Triage was closed as "spam or nonsense".

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder "*The system should be improved IMO, as there would be many places where you have to add a lot of related code to make the post sensible.*" and in many places, askers post way more than the minimum. At any rate, even if more code is needed, it should not be hard to add more explanation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The comment was perfectly fine. The initial version of the question did use

> Stack overflow states I need more words
> Stack overflow states I need more words
> Stack overflow states I need more words
> Stack overflow states I need more words
> Stack overflow states I need more words
> Stack overflow states I need more words

which – as far as *describing a problem or detailing a question* goes – [is nonsense](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonsense#Noun). *Everything* can be taken/received as rude or abusive; when all a comment does is calling a spade a spade, leave it up to the OP to flag it if they would have *actually* taken/received it as rude or abusive.

Comment: And even then, understand that the comment may still be reasonable and the offended party is simply an offended party.

Comment: @user4581301, and that SO may feel like "nonsense" to the party compared to other sites. Like- how can the post editor not be improved? (again, not in this case, generally speaking)

Comment: Could the comment in question have used softer wording? Yes. How I'd make the comment depends on a lot of variables. I probably would have prepended "Please" and appended an explanation of the code-to-description ratio and why it's important.